# Python: Kernel of Matrix over finite field

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I would like to compute the kernel of a matrix `M` of size about 100 x 100, where all entries are modulo 2.
If `M` is a `sympy.Matrix` there is `M.nullspace`, but that computes in the rationals and the computation takes too long.
I have also tested that the kernel is non-trivial (`M.inv_mod(2)` failed).

- So [Sympy: Solving Matrices in a finite field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190182/sympy-solving-matrices-in-a-finite-field) did not help.
- [Test if matrix is invertible over finite field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254654/test-if-matrix-is-invertible-over-finite-field) tells to use Sage for checking invertibility, so I assume Sage can also compute a kernel, but I assume Python has advanced since then (2013).

Any idea?